# Burbank reference in Donald Duck comics

Tags: disney

In the story “Lost in Andes!” by Carl Barks when Donald, Huey, Dewey and Louie arrive in Plain Awful, they are greeted by the inhabitants . They, speaking with an old American accent, ask Donald where he comes from and replies from South Burbank.

In the story “Rocket Wing Saves the Day” again by Carl Barks, the three nephews mention at the start that Rocket Wing took part in a pigeon race from Glendale to Burbank and only came 27th.

In another story(which I can’t recall) donald is kept as a hostage by cannibals and begs them to let him return to Burbank.

Last, in a story featuring the newphews at the Junior Woodchucks camp, they mention that their chief is away at the organization’s headquarters in Burbank.

Is there any reason why the city of Burbank is constantly mentioned by Donald and his nephews? From Scrooge’s side and his sister’s they come from Scotland and live in Duckburg. The only reason I can think of is because the headquarters of Disney are located in Burbank.

Secondly, in the story “Rocket Wing Saves the Day”, the distance from Burbank to Glendale is only 8 km. The nephews are proud of Rocket Wing being a competitive homing pigeon. Given pigeons travel thousands of miles, was this comment meant to be a joke?

Comment: They are *comic* books.

Answer (score 17):

The reason they keep referring to Burbank is because that is where [Walt Disney Studios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walt_Disney_Studios_(Burbank)) (among a few others) is located.

Answer (score -1):

It was before Duckburg was created (Duckburg is not the only name for Donald’s hometown. For example, in The Crocodile Collector it was Duckville.

Comment: @Machavity according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Duck_universe#Duckburg) _"Duckburg was first mentioned in Walt Disney's Comics and Stories #49 in **1944**"_.